# AJAX Request - Add Additional GET request inner loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button at the top a table that displays a modal window to initiate a VOIP call - the ultimate aim is for it to call the first number in the list and then the 2nd number and so on. I've got it working in that it displays the modal window and allows me to initiate a call to the first number in the list.

I now need to update the script so that if the call is successful it then makes another AJAX request in a loop say every 5 seconds to check the status of the call. If the first call is successful it will return the following which I'm storing in the `httpResponseText` variable:

```
Authentication accepted<br/>ActionID = Jo9oACY52cp1
```

I need to parse out the `ActionID` value - in the above example this would be `Jo9oACY52cp1` - and then have another GET request to get the status of the current call by passing in the ActionID as follows:

```
https://www.acme.com/GetStatus.php?ActionID=$action_id
```

This request returns 3 values - ActionID,UID,STATUS - like this:

```
xshsJ6Y2eLDC,1500806656.160,ANSWER
```

I'm only interested in the 3rd value - STATUS - and I need to keep checking the result of this request until the Status does not equal `IN_PROGRESS`. At this point I can then enable the Next Call button and start all over again.

Here's my current table and script:

```js
$("#startBulkContactCall").click(function() {
  $(this).attr('selectedRow', '1');
  contactMobile = $($($('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)').children())[0]).attr('contactMobile');
  contactName = $($($('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)').children())[0]).attr('contactName');
  $('#callNextBulkContact').prop('disabled', true);
  firstURL = "<?php echo $callBackURL ;?>" + defaultCallBackNumber + "<?php echo $contactCallBack ;?>" + contactMobile;
  console.log('firstURL: ' + firstURL);
  $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo $callBackURL ;?>" + defaultCallBackNumber + "<?php echo $contactCallBack ;?>" + contactMobile,
      data: {},
      type: "GET"
    })
    .then(function(data, status, xhr) {
      var httpStatus = status;
      var httpResponseCode = (xhr.status);
      var httpResponseText = (xhr.responseText);
      $('#ajaxSuccessBulk').html('Call in Progress').show();
      $("#startBulkContactCall").prop("disabled", true);
      $("#callNextBulkContact").prop("disabled", true);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var httpResponseCode = (xhr.getAllResponseHeaders);
      var httpResponseText = (xhr.responseText);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an error requesting the call back. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus + ' ' + httpResponseText;
      //make alert visible 
      $('#ajaxError').html(ajaxError).show();
    })
});

$('#callNextBulkContact').click(function() {
  $('#callBulkContact').attr('selectedRow', parseInt($('#callBulkContact').attr('selectedRow')) + 1);
  var rowNum = parseInt($('#callBulkContact').attr('selectedRow'));
  var row = 'table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + rowNum + ') > td:nth-child(2)';
  contactMobile = $($($(row).children())[0]).attr('contactMobile');
  contactName = $($($(row).children())[0]).attr('contactName');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<button type="button" id="bulkCallButton" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> Bulk Call</button>


<table class="table table2 table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="D8F49748-212A-42D8-A188-4C23556027FA">
      <td><a href="details.php?action=contactLink&contactID=D8F49748-212A-42D8-A188-4C23556027FA">John Citizen</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" contactName="John Citizen" contactMobile="0412345678" data-toggle="modal" data-rec-id="1537" data-target="#contactCallModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> 0412 345 678</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="EAD2DCCA-7EFA-B048-AD7D-8FCC0ED5EFD7">
      <td><a href="details.php?action=contactLink&contactID=EAD2DCCA-7EFA-B048-AD7D-8FCC0ED5EFD7">Jonah McMahon</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" contactName="Jonah McMahon" contactMobile="0490876543" data-toggle="modal" data-rec-id="1538" data-target="#contactCallModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> 0490 876 543</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="D9AA7744-E138-4A0E-86A2-B8D0CD2007D6">
      <td><a href="details.php?action=contactLink&contactID=D9AA7744-E138-4A0E-86A2-B8D0CD2007D6">Jake Simpson</a></td>
      <td><a href="#" contactName="Jake Simpson" contactMobile="0405999666" data-toggle="modal" data-rec-id="1577" data-target="#contactCallModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> 0405 999 666</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<div class="modal" id="contactBulkCallModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Call Contact</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Calling </p>
      </div>
      <div id="ajaxError" class="alert alert-danger text-center" role="alert" style="display:none">
        Error Response
      </div>
      <div id="ajaxSuccess" class="alert alert-success text-center" role="alert" style="display:none">
        Call in Progress
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="startBulkContactCall" class="btn btn-success">Start Call</button>
        <button type="button" id="callNextBulkContact" class="btn btn-success">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Never had to do such a complex AJAX request (at least for me) and not sure where to start to add the additional request in loop?

Comment: How do you get the phone numbers?

Comment: The phone numbers are returned from a database query and then displayed in an HTML table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would do: first separate code in functions, it will makes things way easier to follow.

startCall should initiate your call, it receives the callURL the ajax should use. It returns a promise that will resolve once it is made.

monitorCall takes a callID, and a Callback (third param "failed_tries" is used internally.) It will fire the status check using ajax, and call itself every 5 seconds until either 5 consecutive fails happen, or until we get the correct status. The callback is a usual JS callback with error and result as arguments.

getMonitoredCall will join the former two functions together to give a promise that will resolve once the call ends.

getNewCallUrl is used to provide another call. This function will be called before each call, to retrieve who to call. There is work left for you there! It should return a promise that gives the URL as result.

Finally, loopCalls initiates everything and once a call is complete, will call itself again to follow-up on the next call until something fails.

```
function startCall(callURL){
    return $.ajax({
        url: callURL,
        data: {},
        type: "GET"
    }).then(function(data, status, xhr) {
        var httpStatus = status;
        var httpResponseCode = (xhr.status);
        var httpResponseText = (xhr.responseText);
        $('#ajaxSuccessBulk').html('Call in Progress').show();
        $("#startBulkContactCall").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#callNextBulkContact").prop("disabled", true);

        return Promise.resolve(xhr.responseText.match(/ActionID = (.+)/)[1]);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
        var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
        var httpResponseCode = (xhr.getAllResponseHeaders);
        var httpResponseText = (xhr.responseText);
        var ajaxError = 'There was an error requesting the call back. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus + ' ' + httpResponseText;
        //make alert visible 
        $('#ajaxError').html(ajaxError).show();
    });
}
function monitorCall(callID,callback,failed_tries){
    failed_tries = failed_tries || 0;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.acme.com/GetStatus.php',
        data: {ActionID:callID},
        type: "GET"
    }).then(function(data){
        if(data && data.split(',')[2] != "IN_PROGRESS"){
            callback(null,data);
        }else{
            setTimeout(monitorCall.bind(null,callID,callback,0),5000);
        }
    }).fail(function(xhr){
        failed_tries++;
        if(failed_tries>5){
            callback("Error trying to get the status, stopping after 5 consecutive tries.");
        }else{
            setTimeout(monitorCall.bind(null,callID,callback,failed_tries),5000);
        }
    });
}

function getMonitoredCall(callUrl){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        startCall(callUrl).then(function(callID){
            monitorCall(callID,function(err,res){
                if(err){
                    reject(err);
                }else{
                    resolve(res);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

function getNewCallUrl(){
    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://getNewCallUrl/",
        data: {},
        type: "GET"
    }).then(function(data, status, xhr) {
        //Let's presume the request simply returns a call URL.
        return Promise.resolve(data);
    })
    .fail(function(xhr) {
        var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
        var httpResponseCode = (xhr.getAllResponseHeaders);
        var httpResponseText = (xhr.responseText);
        var ajaxError = 'There was an error requesting the call back. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus + ' ' + httpResponseText;
        //make alert visible 
        $('#ajaxError').html(ajaxError).show();
    });
}

function loopCalls(){
    getNewCallUrl().then(function(callUrl){
        return getMonitoredCall(callUrl);
    }).then(function(){setTimeout(loopCalls,5000)});
}
loopCalls();
```

Comment: You may want to correct your code on the first line of `loopCalls()`.

Comment: `getNewCallUrl` won't return the promise until you call it. It should be replaced by `getNewCallUrl().then( ... );`.

Comment: I'm just loading this into my site to test and getting an error on this line `}).then(function(){setTimeout(loopCalls,5000));` - error in console is `Unexpected token ')'`

Comment: Thanks @Salketer - I'm trying to tie this all together now so that when the user clicks the Bulk Call button it displays the modal dialog and when they click the Start Call button it starts the first call. I've setup a JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/76t53623/

I'm not sure how to tie the Start Call button to the appriopriate function - are you able to take a look at this please?

Comment: You need to call loopCalls to start the bulk call. And you also need to remove its call at the end of my script (it was there to show it works). Then you need to fill the inside of the getNewCallUrl function, that function should  do whatever is needed to get the URL to use for a call and return a promise that resolves with that URL.

Comment: I cannot do more than that for you tough. If you'd answer my question in comment, I could help you on that part too.